# Laravel 4 - Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel-4

here is my .htaccess in the root of the project(localhost/laravel_project_name/):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

the contents in laravel_project_name/public have not been changed at all.

So when i access this url "localhost/laravel_project_name/"  it gives this error:

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

and yes mod_rewrite is un-commented.

oh and here is my route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
        return "hello";
});
```

And Im on xampp.

Comment: why isn't anyone answering my question???

Comment: Does Laravel not ship with a default .htaccess file within the /public directory? Also it is worth note to establish how directives are applied, you can see more here.. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Laravel is supposed to be running from the root of your web server, even if it's on localhost. Otherwise the internal rewrites won't work. Also, you should use routes rather than trying to modify the .htaccess.

Comment: ok...none you answered the question on how to omit /public in the url.  And the routes in the app section comes secondary to the .htaccess...the whole point is to have pretty urls like such:  "localhost/laravel_project_name/"...

Comment: Create a [vhost](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) that points to `laravel_project_name/public` this way you don't have to bother with such problems

Comment: or just rewrite/route to server.php which serves the purpose of pretty urls...YET NOT ONE OF YOU KNEW THAT.